# K3 surface $S \subset \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^2$ of bidegree $(2,3)$ has Picard rank 2?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, k3-surfaces

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Pic}{Pic}$The following example is taken from [1, Example 5.8].

Let $S \subset \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^2$ be a general smooth surface of bidegree $(2,3)$, so $S$ is a K3-surface. I want to understand how to compute the Picard lattice of $S$. First we know the Picard group of the surrounding space,
$$\Pic(\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^2) = \mathbb Z \cdot \mathcal O(1,0) \oplus \mathbb Z \cdot \mathcal O(0,1).$$
Choose effective divisors $X = \{pt\} \times \mathbb P^2$ and $Y = \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$, which belong to the two linear systems of the two generators. So we may identify $[X] = \mathcal O(1,0)$ and $[Y] = \mathcal O(0,1)$. We can also calculate the intersections, namely
$$[X]^2 = 0, \quad [X]\cdot[Y] = [\{pt\} \times \mathbb P^1], \quad [Y]^2 = [\mathbb P^1 \times \{pt\}],$$
and furthermore
$$[X]\cdot[Y]^2 = 1, \quad [Y]^3 = 0.$$
We also have $[S] = 2[X] + 3[Y]$, and from this we obtain
$$[X] \cdot [Y] \cdot [S] = 3, \quad [Y]^2 \cdot [S] = 2.$$
Since $\gcd(2,3) = 1$, this means that the restrictions $\mathcal O(1,0)|_S$ and $\mathcal O(0,1)|_S$ are $\mathbb Z$-linearly independent elements in $\Pic(S)$ and we have calculated that the rank $2$ lattice $\Lambda \subset \Pic(S)$ generated by them has intersection matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
However, van Geemen claims actually $\Lambda = \Pic(S)$, i.e. $\Pic(\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^2) \to \Pic(S)$ is also surjective. Why is that the case?

[1] Bert van Geemen, *Some remarks on Brauer groups of K3 surfaces*.

Comment: Looks like a version of Noether-Lefscetz theorem.

Answer (score 1):

One can apply the following version of Noether-Lefschetz theorem. It can be found in [this paper](https://faculty.tcu.edu/snollet/I-70.pdf).

[image: Moishezon's version on Noether-Lefschetz]

One thing need to be highlighted here is that the theorem assumed the hyperplane section need to be *very general*, namely, complement of countable union of divisors in the moduli. Geemen only assumed K3 surface being *general*. I'm not sure if it is a typo, or I missed something.